# Inverting table

Tags: google-sheets

This is the table I have:

```
        A                   B
1       Title1      |       Title
2            
3       0           |       # of teachers
4            
5       11          |       # of students
6            
7       Not active  |       Active?
8            
9            
10           
11      Title2      |       Title
12           
13      3           |       # of teachers
14           
15      5           |       # of students
16           
17      Not active  |       Active?
18           
19           
20           
21      Title3      |       Title
22           
23      10          |       # of teachers
24           
25      22          |       # of students
26           
27      Not active  |       Active?
```

I'd like to "invert" it in another sheet to have Title, # of teachers, # of students and Active? as headers and then the values under the right column (each entry in a separate row).
I was trying to use MATCH without much luck..

This retrieves just the first Title (every time):

```
=index(SheetWithTable!$A:$A,match("Title",SheetWithTable!$B:$B,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please copy your sheet and in that copy select B1:B7, Copy, Paste special into D1 with Paste transpose. In D3, copied across to J3 and down to suit:

```
=index($A1:$A11,match(D$1,$B1:$B11,0))
```

Select all, Copy, Paste special, Paste values only. Filter Column B to deselect `# of teachers` only and delete all rows but Row 1. Clear filter. Delete Columns I, G, E, C, B, A.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula in cell D1:

```
={{B1,B3,B5,B7};{filter(A:A,B:B=B1),filter(A:A,B:B=B3),filter(A:A,B:B=B5),filter(A:A,B:B=B7)}}
```

Or you can try:

```
={{"Title","# of teachers","# of students","Active?"};{filter(A:A,B:B="Title"),filter(A:A,B:B="# of teachers"),filter(A:A,B:B="# of students"),filter(A:A,B:B="Active?")}}
```

Have a look at the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 3 titles in a table, you can rotate it:

```
rotateArray = function(array) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      newArray[i].push(array[j][i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
};
```

http://dtab.io/sheets/560b8efd6faeb39d2a70ad1e